# Revit API get coordinates for OST_Viewers and OST_Level type

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I need to find coordinates for `OST_Viewers` and `OST_Level` types. I get them with this code:

```
var vieversCollection = 
  new FilteredElementCollector(uiDoc.Document)
    .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Viewers);

var levelsCollection = 
  new FilteredElementCollector(uiDoc.Document,)
    .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels);
```

I tried to use the `Location` property for them, and cast it to `LocationPoint`, but it always returns `null`.
What method should I use for coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Elements in `BuiltInCategory.OST_Viewers` cannot have a location or any other coordinates because it is just a view. It is like an unlimited 3D-cube. Are you sure you want to retrieve exact coordinates?

`Level` cannot have a `Location` either. `Level` has only one coordinate - `Elevation`. You can get it via the `Level.Elevation` property.

Comment: What about a section marker in the main view that references another view?  Inside the main view you can re-size the section marker line segment referring to the other view without changing the other view.  This means that the section marker should have some kind of coordinates in the main view.